# Can I safely shutdown WSL2 without stopping services like mysql and apache?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, shutdown, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am using the classic LAMP development environment with WSL2(`Ubuntu`) on Windows 10.

I would like to shutdown WSL2 after finishing my work in order to be able to free resources (the Vmmem process can be resource consuming).

Can I safely shutdown WSL2 (`wsl --shutdown`) without stopping services like mysql and apache, **or should I stop them manually before shutting down WSL2**?

Does it matter? Is there any good practice or could something go wrong? I would not like to screw up my environment (databases or apache, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would not like to screw up my environment (databases or apache, etc.)

For safety you should shut down those services first.

You should be able to write a small batch file that shuts everything down in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some limited testing (see below) with `wsl --terminate <distro>` and `wsl --shutdown`, and it does *not* appear to send a `SIGTERM` (nor any other signal) to subprocesses to allow them to terminate safely.

As @DavidPostill mentions in his [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1592445/1210833), I agree that you should make sure to safely terminate those services first.

##### Alternative

As an alternative to coming up with your own scripts to do this, I would recommend starting these services under a process supervisor like (the aptly named) [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html).  With that in place, you can issue a single `sudo supervisorctl stop all` to safely terminate (via a default `SIGTERM`) all of the associated services.

##### Limited testing notes

My quick-and-dirty testing here involved using the Fish shell (could have been Bash or something else, but that's my preferred shell) to register signal handlers.

First, I did a:

```
function exit_test --on-event fish_exit
    touch ~/exiting
end
```

From another (Bash) shell in the same Ubuntu distribution/instance, I then ran:

```
pkill -SIGTERM fish
```

This did *not* trigger the function, since `~/exiting` wasn't created, but it did generate a `Terminated` message from Fish itself before it exited.

---

Likewise:

```
pkill -SIGKILL fish
```

... generated a `Killed` message from Fish, but no `~/exited` file creation.

---

```
pkill -SIGHUP fish
```

<sub>Note-to-self: Not `SIGHUG` ...</sub>

This *did* generate `~/exiting`, but no message on the terminal.

---

On the other hand, from PowerShell:

```
wsl --terminate Ubuntu-22.04
```

... did not generate any message from Fish on the terminal nor did it generate the `~/exiting` file.

---

Next up, I created a trap for most every signal in Fish:

```
for signal in $(string split ' ' $(trap -l))
    if ! contains $signal "POLL" "STKFLT" "CHLD"
        trap "echo $signal >> ~/signals" $signal
    end
end
```

I excluded `POLL` and `STKFLT` because Fish would not let me create a trap on them.  I excluded `CHLD` because it triggers whenever a subprocess ends (pretty much every prompt and then some).

For the complete list of signals being trapped:

```
> trap -l
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT
CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH POLL PWR SYS
```

Based on that, I reran the above tests.

```
pkill -SIGTERM fish
pkill -SIGHUP fish
pkill -SIGINT fish
pkill -SIGUSR1 fish
... etc.
```

All properly triggered the trap and wrote the corresponding signal to the `~/signals`.  Note that, because of the `trap`, the shell doesn't exit.

---

```
pkill -SIGKILL fish
```

Again, generated a `Killed` message, and (as expected) did not trigger the trap.

---

```
wsl --shutdown
# or
wsl --terminate Ubuntu-22.04
```

Did *not* trigger any trap nor message.

Based on this, it does not appear to me that WSL sends *any* signal to subprocesses when terminating or shutting down.

Comment: Does Windows shutdown send any signals to WSL2 and/or it's services?

Comment: @pbies What part of *"limited testing"* did you not understand!?  Kidding - Of course.  That's a really good question.  I poked around some more, and I've updated with my findings.  Thanks for requesting the additional info!